TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable (although exactly copied from working source)
I'm currently doing some changes in a modded map of a game and copied the following code from a tutorial:
from PIL import Image


def update_pixel(p):
     channel = p[0] + (256 * p[1])
     state = channel // 32
     index = channel % 32
     new_channel = (state * 64) + index
     return (new_channel % 256, new_channel // 256, 0)


img = Image.open("densityMap_fruits.png")
list_of_pixels = list(img.getdata())
new_list_of_pixels = list(map(update_pixel, list_of_pixels))
img.putdata(new_list_of_pixels)
img.save("densityMap_fruits_new.png")

After that, I need to run this code in Windows PowerShell, however when I try, I get the error: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
I don't really know what went wrong here, I copied the exact code from the tutorial and it worked fine there.

It seems that p is an integer. Which would mean that list_of_pixels is a list of integers.

This code assumes that the image has three components.  The error you get is what I'd expect if the image actually had only one component per pixel - either a palette-based image, or grayscale.

If I understand the PIL documentation correctly, open() does not load the images' data. Could that be causing the error? It states that you should call load() on the result of open() to get the pixels.

@ZenielDanaku: Anything that needs pixel data calls load if the image hasn’t been loaded, getdata included.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
